# Expectation of MLE estimator for $\sigma^{2}$ Multiple Regression model

Tags: regression, expected-value

Given Y = $X\beta + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^{2}I_n)$,

Under this setting, I get the MLE estimator for $\sigma^{2} = \frac{1}{n} ||Y - HY||^{2}$, where H is the hat matrix $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$,

now I would like to check whether the MLE estimator is unbiased or not, this is my calculation steps:
[image]

My question is that I am not sure how to calculate $E(Y^{T}HY)$ since if we expand it we are gonna get $E(\epsilon^{T}H\epsilon)$, and it seems confusing for me to compute this value

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write $Y^THY = tr(Y^THY)=tr(HYY^T)$, so you have $E[Y^THY] = tr(HE[YY^T])$.

and since $E[YY^T] = Cov(Y) = \sigma^2 I_n$  you get $E[Y^THY] = \sigma^2 tr(H)$,

and $tr(H) = tr(I_d) = d$ (assuming the dimension of $X$ is $n$-by-$d$)

so the expectation of the MLE is $\sigma^2(1 - d/n)$ and it is biased for small $n$.

Comment: +1.  But note that this estimator is biased for *all* $n,$ not just "small" $n.$

Comment: Well yes I guess in small I mean $n < \infty$